# How to replicate existing graphite server to a new one using carbon relay

Tags: replication, graphite

So, we have a standalone graphite node which is behind a cname and collecting all the metrics. If this goes down,it's not going to be good.So, my question is how do I not only replicate all the existing whisper data to another node, but also setup replication in place using carbon relay. What would the migration workflow look like in short? How should I configure the carbon relay? I want to do this in as transparent way as possible with minimum downtime.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I understand you need some help. But it is hard to see what is going on without your sample code/data etc. Would you please be able to modify your question? Then, people will be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

The migration will require a minimal unavoidable downtime.

I would proceed by:

- decrease lifetime of you cname in your dns server (it will a lower bound of  the duration of your downtime)
- prepare a second server with aggregators, cache and a relay pointing to both boxes (replication factor 2), but stop the relay
- stop graphite on your first server (downtime start now)
- change the cname to point to the second server
- archive all metrics on the first server, copy to the second, extract them
- start the relay (end of downtime)
- at time of dns change + ttl, all your clients will have moved the second relay, all data is written on both servers

You can then start to make your setup more reliable with a relay on the first server (sharing a virtual ip for instance).

On our setup we have separated relay servers (2 of them in active/active) from aggregator+cache servers.

Redundancy in graphite is however tricky when a server is down since it won't fetch missed updates when up again, you'll have to do it manually.